# Using Selenium with ChromeDriver on Windows - Error: "Lock file can not be created"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

My script used to work but suddenly it has stopped working.
I have updated Selenium to the latest version (3.0.2) and I'm using the latest version of ChromeDriver (2.26).

Here's an excerpt of the code that I think is causing the problem:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:￥Users￥username￥AppData￥Local￥Google￥Chrome￥User Data￥Profile 1")
```

The code looks fine to me though, so I suspect that it might be a Google Chrome issue rather than a Selenium one. My other identical script without the chrome profile option (i.e. Default Profile) works perfectly.

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
[7256:21580:1214/033134:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(340)] Lock file can not be created! Error code: 32
[7256:21580:1214/033134:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1703)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to some zombie Chrome instance locking the profile specified in the "user-data-dir" argument. Forcibly stopping Selenium mid-run tends to leave them behind.

Try going to the specified profile directory and deleting the file named "lockfile". If the OS complains that the file is in use, close all visible Chrome instances and examine (via Task manager) whether there are zombie Chrome instances and try killing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Google Chrome, you have to start your script using Administrator privileges