# Building Error related to Chrome/chromium/Selenium

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, build, electron

Error while building and starting application with "yarn start":

```
ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(465) Lock file can not be created! Error code: 3
```

Found that error while building a cloned electron project on a windows x64 device.
searched for that error and found that link that may have the answer but I can't figure it out.

Here it is: [process_singleton_win.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/32352ad08ee673a4d43e8593ce988b224f6482d3/chrome/browser/process_singleton_win.cc)
Probably error produced on line 439
But I can't get what line 424 means
Also found that on stackoverflow for a previous question I think is related but still can't fix it.
[Error: "Lock file can not be created"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984556/15229260)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it on Ubuntu it may work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).